# Object Recovery via a date with spring data

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have a problem recovering an object via a date I work with spring data the problem is that the object returns is null despite this object is not null
Thank you for reply me please
cordially

```
@Repository
public interface ProspectStatistiqueRepository extends JpaRepository<ProspectStatique, Long> {
    @Query("select p from ProspectStatique p where p.date_consultation =:date_consultation")
    public ProspectStatique getProspectCountByDate(@Param("date_consultation") Date date_consultation);

}

@Autowired
ProspectStatistiqueRepository prospectStatistiqueRepository;
@GetMapping("/products")
public ProductStatique findProductNumberBydate(@RequestParam String date) throws CustomerException, ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date dateConvert = format.parse(date);
    System.out.println("date param " + date);
    System.out.println("dateConvert variable" + dateConvert);
    ProductStatique pp = productStatiqueService.getProductCount(dateConvert);
    return pp;
}
```

Comment: Please add what is printed by the System.outs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used **JpaRepository** so you can use "Between","After" and "Before" to deal with date :

```
@Repository
public interface ProspectStatistiqueRepository extends JpaRepository<ProspectStatique, Long> {

//1-Between
    public List<ProspectStatique> findByDate_consultationBetween(Date date1,Date date2);

//2-After
    public List<ProspectStatique> findByDate_consultationAfter(Date date);

//3-Befor
    public List<ProspectStatique> findByDate_consultationBefore(Date date);

}
```

for more information you can see spring doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html