# Spring data jpa, native query Hibernate exception

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa

I want to delete records which are one day older , I am using SQL query in Spring data JPA as below:

```
@Query(value = "delete from tableName data where data.CREATION_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteRecordsOlderThanYesterday();
```

I am getting exception as:

Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not extract result set metadata
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not extract result set metadata

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

What is wrong with above code or is there any other way to do it in HQL?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you are defining queries from SQL Statements (UPDATE, DELETE) You need to use `@Modifying` annotation (from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository`). Try this:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from tableName data where data.CREATION_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1", 
        nativeQuery = true)
void deleteRecordsOlderThanYesterday();
```

Comment: @infiniteRefactor...thanks for your answer, i think u r right and i will accept ur answer after checking ur answer on my sys

Answer (score 1):

you'd better use **JpaRepository** and use **findByStartDateBefore** and you dont need to use @Query

```
 public List<yourResult> findByStartDateBefore(Date date);
```

for more information you can see spring doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

and this question [Object Recovery via a date with spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468411/object-recovery-via-a-date-with-spring-data/43468901#43468901)

Comment: Hello Azzabi, I am able to delete using deleteByCreationDateBefore , thanks